# Pull a DATEDIFF between Rows with Distinct value and WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to generate a DATEDIFF to calculate SLA adherence, but the table info I need to perform the DATEDIFF is replicated in rows (instead of a start time column, end time column).

As such, I need to set a WHERE statement for the same column, using 2 different StatusIds to DATEDIFF those two timestamps.

For example,

```
PackageId | StatusId | rowDateModified
--------------------------------------
1              1        2019-06-01 00:41
1              2        2019-06-01 01:30
```

Ideally, I need to be able to calculate how long it took between package creation (StatusId = 1) and package completion (StatusId = 2) for an infinite number of rows, where the PackageId is Distinct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select packageid,
       datediff(day,
                max(case when statusid = 1 then rowdatemodified end),
                max(case when statusid = 2 then rowdatemodified end)
               )
from t
group by packageid
```