# Using Conditional Aggregation in SubQuery

Tags: sql, sql-server

Thanks to the help of another user, I was able to use Conditional Aggregation to get the data point I need. I now need to implement this into an existing query in order to get an SLA % for a date range (rather than each package). Previous post for reference: [Pull a DATEDIFF between Rows with Distinct value and WHERE Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56763011/pull-a-datediff-between-rows-with-distinct-value-and-where-clause/56763021#56763021)

The below query was used when the assumption that the 2 timestamps in 'PackageTable' were accurate enough to calculate SLA. Since I found out they were not, I have to run the query on a different table (PackageTable_Audit) that basically records events in a row when a package moves from LifeCycleStatusId = 1 (creation) to LifeCycleStatusId = 3 (Assigned) to LifeCycleStatusId = 5 (Completed). As such, the SLA adherence % is the amount of packages that were completed in X seconds / total packages. Since I can't use a simple DATEDIFF in a sub-query, and thus have to use the aggregate function to get a DATEDIFF between rows, I'm not sure how to work it into the query.

I've updated my old query with the Conditional Aggregate, but I get the following Error:

"Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery."

Query:

```
-- VARIABLE DECLARATION AND INITIALIZATION
DECLARE @StartDate varchar(10);
DECLARE @EndDate varchar(10);

SET @StartDate = '2019-06-01';
SET @EndDate = '2019-06-31';

-- TABLE DECLARATION ##################################################
DECLARE @TABLE1 TABLE("No. Packages in SLA" INT, "Total Packages" INT, "SLA %" FLOAT)
--#####################################################################

-- WHAT GETS INSERTED INTO TABLE 1
INSERT INTO @TABLE1
SELECT
A.NUM, A.DENOM, CAST(A.NUM AS FLOAT)/A.DENOM*100

FROM
(
-- COLUMN SELECTION. TWO NUMBERS WILL REPRESENT A NUM AND A DENOM
SELECT 
    (SELECT SUM(CASE
            WHEN
                datediff(second, MAX(CASE WHEN LifeCycleStatusId = 2 THEN rowDateModified END),
            MAX(CASE WHEN LifeCycleSTatusId = 5 THEN rowDateModified END)
            ) < 172800
                    THEN 1
                        ELSE 0
                            END) AS IN_SLA
        FROM PackageTable WITH (nolock)
        WHERE lifecyclestatusid = 5
   AND rowDateCreated BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
        AS NUM,
    (SELECT COUNT(PackageGuid) As No_Packages
        FROM PackageTable WITH (nolock)
        WHERE lifecyclestatusid = 5
   AND rowDateCreated BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
        AS DENOM
) A

SELECT "No. Packages in SLA", "Total Packages", "SLA %"
FROM @TABLE1
```

Comment: Please describe the issue with current query. This is hard to understand as your conditional aggregation does not match previous post. And what table in *hence needing the aggregate query on a different table*?

Comment: Sorry for being confusing, the query above is what I was using to calculate SLA % - I pasted the old query and I've since updated - once I found out that table 'PackageTable' wasn't accurate, I created the post for Conditional Aggregate to pull data from 'PackageTable_Audit' - when I tried inputting in the conditional aggregate function, I get an error